# Start the docker container under a different user

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

We need to have access to a shared resource in the active directory (file share) from a docker container which is running a **dotnetcore api**. The Api is started with (dotnet `api.dll`).
The current user in the docker contrainer is `ContainerAdministrator`.

We are using **Windows 2016 server**

Comment: I windows I cannot help you, but in Linux I'd do in Dockerfile: `USER <your_user>
ENV HOME /home/<your_user>`

Answer (score 1):

Finally  made it work.
Added a powershell script that run "net use" first and the dotnet command after.

Use cmd in the docker file to start the ps script.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Windows based authentication infrastructure first. It's not simple DockerFile change. Details are here in series of blog articles both for .NET core and full .NET framework.
https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2017/09/09/enabling-integrated-windows-authentication-in-windows-docker-container/